# Ubuntu problem with console

Tags: upgrade, wine, dpkg

I have a problem with install update from Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.
when I want install it, so popup show me what I have running application on background.. but I don't have application.

Yesterday I was wanted installed Wine on this ubuntu But I cant make it.
When I write command for install wine, so after I write apt update I have this:

Сущ:3 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu eoan InRelease  and more aplications..

After I write apt upgrade
And it show me reading is complete but I have error and it want apt --fix-broken install for fix broken packages..

So next i write `apt --fix-broken install` and console write me this

```
dpkg: error processing wine-stable package (--configure):
 dependency problems - leave not configured
dpkg: package dependencies do not allow you to configure the winehq-stable package:
 winehq-stable depends on wine-stable (= 5.0.0 ~ eoan), however:
  The wine-stable package has not yet been configured.

dpkg: error processing package winehq-stable (--configure):
 dependency problems - leave not configured
Errors occurred while processing the following packages:
```

And when it want installed so it write me this problem with this component:

```
 libhx509-5-heimdal:i386
 libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386
 libgssapi3-heimdal:i386
 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386
 libldap-2.4-2:i386
 wine-stable-i386:i386
 wine-stable
 winehq-stable
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

I have this all code:

```
root@zetx:~# apt update
Сущ:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease                       
Сущ:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease                
Сущ:3 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu eoan InRelease                  
Сущ:4 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease                       
Сущ:5 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease
Сущ:6 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports InRelease
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово            
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Может быть обновлено 20 пакетов. Запустите «apt list --upgradable» для их показа.
root@zetx:~# apt upgrade
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Вы можете запустить «apt --fix-broken install» для исправления этих ошибок.
Следующие пакеты имеют неудовлетворённые зависимости:
E: Неудовлетворённые зависимости. Попытайтесь выполнить «apt --fix-broken install», не указывая имени пакета (или указав решение).
root@zetx:~# apt --fix-broken install
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Исправление зависимостей… Готово
Следующие пакеты устанавливались автоматически и больше не требуются:
  gir1.2-geocodeglib-1.0 gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-gudev-1.0
  gir1.2-udisks-2.0 grilo-plugins-0.3-base gstreamer1.0-gtk3 guile-2.2-libs
  libboost-date-time1.67.0 libboost-filesystem1.67.0 libboost-iostreams1.67.0
  libboost-locale1.67.0 libcdr-0.1-1 libclucene-contribs1v5 libclucene-core1v5
  libcmis-0.5-5v5 libcolamd2 libcurl4 libdazzle-1.0-0 libe-book-0.1-1 libeot0
  libepubgen-0.1-1 libetonyek-0.1-1 libfreerdp-client2-2 libfreerdp2-2
  libgc1c2 libgom-1.0-0 libgpgmepp6 libgpod-common libgpod4 libgrilo-0.3-0
  liblangtag-common liblangtag1 liblirc-client0 liblua5.3-0 libminiupnpc17
  libmspub-0.1-1 libodfgen-0.1-1 liborcus-0.14-0 libqqwing2v5 libraw19
  librevenge-0.0-0 librsync2 libsgutils2-2 libsuitesparseconfig5 libvncclient1
  libwinpr2-2 libxmlsec1 libxmlsec1-nss lp-solve media-player-info
  python3-bcrypt python3-fasteners python3-future python3-lib2to3
  python3-lockfile python3-mako python3-markupsafe python3-monotonic
  python3-paramiko syslinux syslinux-common syslinux-legacy usb-creator-common
Для их удаления используйте «apt autoremove».
Обновлено 0 пакетов, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 20 пакетов не обновлено.
Установлено или удалено не до конца 9 пакетов.
Необходимо скачать 0 B/48,3 kB архивов.
После данной операции объём занятого дискового пространства возрастёт на 0 B.
dpkg: зависимости пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет libhx509-5-heimdal:i386:
 libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 зависит от libwind0-heimdal (>= 1.4.0+git20110226), одн
ако:
  Пакет libwind0-heimdal:i386 не установлен.

dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 (--configure):
 проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным
Отчёт apport не записан, так как сообщение об ошибке указывает на повторную ошиб
ку от предыдущего отказа.
                         Отчёт apport не записан, так как сообщение об ошибке ук
азывает на повторную ошибку от предыдущего отказа.
                                                  dpkg: зависимости пакетов не п
озволяют настроить пакет libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386:
 libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 зависит от libwind0-heimdal (>= 1.4.0+git20110226), о
днако:
  Пакет libwind0-heimdal:i386 не установлен.

dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 (--configure):
 проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным
dpkg: зависимости пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет libgssapi3-heimdal:i386:
 libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 зависит от libheimntlm0-heimdal (>= 1.4.0+git20110226),
 однако:
  Пакет libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 пока не настроен.

dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 (--configure):
 проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным
dpkОтчёт apport не записан, так как сообщение об ошибке указывает на повторную о
шибку от предыдущего отказа.
                            Отчёт apport не записан, так как достигнуто значение
 MaxReports
           Отчёт apport не записан, так как достигнуто значение MaxReports
                                                                          Отчёт 
apport не записан, так как достигнуто значение MaxReports
                                                         Отчёт apport не записан
, так как достигнуто значение MaxReports
                                        Отчёт apport не записан, так как достигн
уто значение MaxReports
                       g: зависимости пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет libkr
b5-26-heimdal:i386:
 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 зависит от libhx509-5-heimdal (>= 1.4.0+git20110226), о
днако:
  Пакет libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 пока не настроен.
 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 зависит от libwind0-heimdal (>= 1.6~git20120311), однак
о:
  Пакет libwind0-heimdal:i386 не установлен.

dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 (--configure):
 проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным
dpkg: зависимости пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет libldap-2.4-2:i386:
 libldap-2.4-2:i386 зависит от libgssapi3-heimdal (>= 1.4.0+git20110226), однако
:
  Пакет libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 пока не настроен.

dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета libldap-2.4-2:i386 (--configure):
 проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным
dpkg: зависимости пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет wine-stable-i386:i386:
 wine-stable-i386:i386 зависит от libldap-2.4-2 (>= 2.4.7), однако:
  Пакет libldap-2.4-2:i386 пока не настроен.

dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета wine-stable-i386:i386 (--configure):
 проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным
dpkg: зависимости пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет wine-stable:
 wine-stable зависит от wine-stable-i386 (= 5.0.0~eoan), однако:
  Пакет wine-stable-i386:i386 пока не настроен.

dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета wine-stable (--configure):
 проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным
dpkg: зависимости пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет winehq-stable:
 winehq-stable зависит от wine-stable (= 5.0.0~eoan), однако:
  Пакет wine-stable пока не настроен.

dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета winehq-stable (--configure):
 проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 libhx509-5-heimdal:i386
 libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386
 libgssapi3-heimdal:i386
 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386
 libldap-2.4-2:i386
 wine-stable-i386:i386
 wine-stable
 winehq-stable
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

And maybe problem is in the starting system. Because when i want start Ubuntu so first i need turn on power in ntb, after I need put on the F9 and select position with Ubuntu text.

When i was installed ubuntu, so i was installed from usb disk, after i disconect USB and next..

When i dont take F9, so ntb restarting with black background and text around not fount boot devices and restarting and restarting.
Can i repair it? How? Or how can i reinstall ubuntu?

Comment: Welcome Ask Ubuntu  Zloy, AskUbuntu is a Q&A platform not a forum. Use the small [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1231071/edit) link under the question text, to make updates and add information. See [About]